# Enable developer dashboard question for SP2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, 2016, dashboard

I failed to find official article about how to enable Developer Dashboard for SP2016. The only one I can find is [this old one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ff512745(v%3Doffice.14)#how-to-enable-the-developer-dashboard) for SP2010 foundation.

The PowerShell script it suggested is :

```
(Get-SPFarm).PerformanceMonitor.DeveloperDashboardLevel = "On"
```

However I also find some other blogs recommend this one:

```
$var = Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.DeveloperDashboardSettings;  
$var.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On  
$var.Update()
```

Are they actually the same? Or they have different behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to enable developer dashboard:

```
$ContentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService   
$DevDashboard = $ContentService.DeveloperDashboardSettings    
$DevDashboard.DisplayLevel = "On"    
$DevDashboard.Update()
```

**Note**: Make sure that you have an active and running "Usage and Health Service Application" service application as developer dashboard directly depends on it.

[image]

**Reference**: [Enable Developer Dashboard In SharePoint Server 2016](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/enable-developer-dashboard-in-sharepoint-server-2016)

Comment: Is the result same as Michael's answer? Displaylevel should be a string or a level datatype?

Comment: @MarkL, currently I don't have access to 2016 environment. So, didn't get a chance to test this. But, this should work for you. please try at your end once.

Comment: I tested both answer work. Thanks.

Comment: Glad, it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a test in my SP16, The Official  PowerShell  example
`(Get-SPFarm).PerformanceMonitor.DeveloperDashboardLevel = "On"` doesnot work. I get the error like this:

[image]

I find this article with the similar issue: https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-2010-developer-dashboard.html

You need to use the second one. This works for me.

```
$var = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService.DeveloperDashboardSettings;  
$var.DisplayLevel = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPDeveloperDashboardLevel]::On  
$var.Update()
```